# Strange behavior of python imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I've encountered a strange behavior of python imports. Python version is 3.5.2. It looks like if one names a subpackage with the same name as some standard module (like logging) - it shadows it for some reason.

Here's a toy example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/areshytko/src
```

`src/bar/__init__.py` - empty

`src/bar/main.py`:

```
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("success")
```

`src/bar/logging/__init__.py` - empty

python bar/main.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bar/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/unittest/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "/home/areshytko/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 273, in <module>
    class _CapturingHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'Handler'
```

Comment: The problem isn't naming a subpackage the same thing as a standard library module. The problem is that `python bar/main.py` puts `bar` on the import path, so your `logging` directory looks like a top-level package (and *also* a subpackage of `bar`, which will be treated as an entirely separate but mostly identical package by the import system).

Comment: What is your current directory? Looks like `src`, which means Python will pick up your local logging module first.

Comment: Try this instead: `cd ~ ; python3 -m bar.main`.

Comment: See [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for additional information (though it doesn't cover the `sys.path` manipulation you'll need to additionally do if you want to be able to run `bar/main.py` like this).